Считывание объекта с помощью ReadProcessMemory C#
Увидел в чужом коде такое:
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] [Out] object lpBuffer, int dwSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

Большее всего меня заинтересовал третий аргумент. Попробовал повторить:
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
extern public static bool ReadProcessMemory(nint hProcess, nint lpBaseAddress, object? lpBuffer, int nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

Всегда выдаёт 0(Я тестил на int).
Сделал как надо через через массив байт, данные есть
Исходя из этого могу сделать вывод что почему-то не передаётся ссылка
Короче есть ли способ превратить массив байт в объект или сразу счесть объект?
Контекст:
Мой
public T? GetObject<T>(nint offset)
{
    T? result = default;
    
    if (!Kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(target.Handle, Module.BaseAddress + offset, result, Marshal.SizeOf<T>(), out int readsBytes))
        throw new Exception($"Memory read error(code: {Kernel32.GetLastError()})");

    return result;
}

Чужой:
[NullableContext(0)]
public static T Read<[IsUnmanaged] T>(IntPtr Address) where T : struct, ValueType
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf<T>();
    object buffer = default(T);
    int lpNumberOfBytesRead;
    Memory.ReadProcessMemory(Memory._proc.Handle, Address, buffer, size, out lpNumberOfBytesRead);
    if (lpNumberOfBytesRead != size)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    return (T)((object)buffer);
}


"Короче есть ли способ превратить массив байт в объект или сразу счесть объект?" нет и не будет, объект с точки зрения рантайма - это что? это тип объекта, это ссылка на объект, и это байты реализации [экземпляра] объекта в куче, и как можно всё одним махом да ещё и одним массивом раскидать сие по памяти рантайма - это загадашно, впрочем некоторые решения есть, но они никак не позволяют "вот взять и полечить от всех болезней"

более того, всякие выкрутасы с рантаймом даром могут и не пройти, рантайм падает от любого даже тихого чиха, он хрустальный или типа того, и вы можете наступить на рантайм так что даже и сами этого не заметите - это я всего лишь про то, что если рантайм не упал от выкрутасов, это вовсе не значит что он не упадёт через неделю, причём вы даже и не поймёте от чего всё завалилось

существуют весьма элегантные решения замутить быстро например массив структур из массива байт, за О(1), но условный массив должен быть, он должен сидеть как какая то память. или неуправляемая или управляемая, её можно быстро ре-интерпретировать во что либо - это да, это существует, но основная проблема не в этом а в коллекторе - все эти выкрутасы с памятью [для коллектора] сразу проваливаются в лох как в первичную чёрную дыру, а дальше вы ничего толком [быстро] не получите

как минимум в "чужом" коде пытаются выгребсти структуру и её превращают в объект, а вы гребёте объект, и это кардинально разные штуки, причём в "чужом" коде зачем то ещё и боксят всё это, свой код попробуйте тоже "забоксить", и это может решить проблему, только это не решит проблему того, что у рантайма от таких выкрутасов мозги скручиваются, и рантайм все выкрутасы сразу отправляет подальше в лох, и надо ли вам это?

Могу посоветовать вместо атрибута DllImport использовать LibraryImport (если версия дотнета позволяет). Полезные ссылки: 1, 2. (Не пугайтесь размеру последней статьи, ищите в тексте LibraryImport - там подробное описание, как это работает.) Сгенерированный код, возможно, даст дополнительную информацию.

Потыкался ещё немного и пришёл к такому коду:
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
extern public static bool ReadProcessMemory(nint hProcess, nint lpBaseAddress, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)][Out] object lpBuffer, int nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

public T GetObject<T>(nint offset)
{
    object result = default(T);

    if (!Kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(target.Handle, Module.BaseAddress + offset, result, Marshal.SizeOf<T>(), out int readsBytes))
        throw new Exception($"Memory read error(code:{Kernel32.GetLastError()})");

    return (T)result;
}

Я всё ещё не особо понимаю почему так а не иначе, но оно вроде работает

Могу посоветовать исключения более правильно бросать throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); то есть, вам не нужен свой GetLastError, он уже есть в .NET. Win32Exception сам расшифрует код ошибки, и будет легче понять, что произошло.

@aepot Спасибо за совет

а что работает? вы пишете что "работает", а конкретно что "работает"? вот вы дёрнули объект "хитрым способом", а если этот объект наследуется от другого объекта? а рантайм ничего про это не знает и не должен, вы дёрнули объект - а система типов от этого не развалилась? тут вопросов масса, и всё это нужно тестировать

Если бы я искал лёгкие пути я бы писал на C++

Читайте что такое упаковка значимого типа, и в каких случаях она происходит - тогда и поймёте почему переменная result должна быть object.

плюсики - это хорошо и замечательно) но в такие крайности я бы "впадать" не стал бы, и на самом деле рантайму много чего не хватает, например пользовательской настраиваемой кучи, или например жёсткого задания поколения объекту и так далее - тут тз с телефонную книжку получится, и вот это нужно решать - это да, а так то я не против "экспериментов", но "эксперименты" в 95% случаев ни к чему не приводят и это пол-беды, но чаще всего "эксперименты" не верно интерпретируются - и вот это беда

Опыта мало не бывает
